# How to add values to an object

Tags: java, arrays, object, compiler-errors

I try to learn Java and have a question. 
I created a class Color. This class contains an constructor for "color" with 3 int values (red, green, blue). Then I have an array with a lot of color elements.

Now I want to add 4 of this elements to one and divide it, so I get the average of each int value.

But eclipse says, that the operator + is undefined.

```
Color sum = new Color(red, green, blue)
for (int i = 0; i < length; i ++) {
     sum = sum + array[i];
}

public Color(int r, int g, int b){
    this.red=r;
    this.green=g;
    this.blue=b;
}
```

How can I add the values of each array element to a sum? The elements in the array are from the type color.

Comment: the sum is not defined for your object, if it contained a `string` what should java do ? You have to sum the red,green,blue values manually

Comment: When you say "an array of color elements", did you mean **C**olor, i.e., your class Color?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no operator overloading in Java. You'd have to handle each value separately:

```
int avgRed = 0;
int avgGreen = 0;
int avgBlue = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < length; i ++) {
    avgRed += array[i].getRed();
    avgBlue += array[i].getBlue();
    avgGreen += array[i].getGreen();
}
Color avgColor = new Color(avgRed / length, avgBlue / length, avgGreen / length);
```

Answer (score 1):

**sum** variable is a `Color` and the concatenation in the form

```
sum = sum + array[i];
```

is not defined, so the compiler can not understand how to resolve such operation

you could maybe consider something like

```
sum.red +=  array[i];
```

is array[i] is holding an integer or:

```
sum.red +=  array[i].red;
```

if the array is an array of colors

Answer (score 0):

Sum is an object not variable.You can add value to its associated parameter.

for example :

```
sum.red = sum.red+array[i].red
```

Comment: This is not an answer but a comment.

Comment: @aubin I have edited :) Now its clear ? btw I don't have access to comment.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the `+` operator to do what you have in mind, but you could add an `add` method to your `Color` class so that you could then write:

```
Color sum = new Color(red, green, blue)
 for (int i = 0; i < length; i ++) {
    sum = sum.add(array[i]);
```

Let's assume for this discussion that adding `Color`s means we add the red part of the one to the red part of the other, green to green, blue to blue.  Your `add` method would look like this:

```
    public Color add(Color other) {
        return new Color(this.red + other.red, 
                         this.green + other.green,
                         this.blue + this.blue);
    }
```